# Cannot select a profile from CiviEvent online registration setup

Tags: civievent, profile, joomla

I am running CiviCRM 4.6.10 and Joomla 2.5.28 and I can't select a profile when I turn on online registration for an event. It's weird because I can select a profile for a contribution page but just not events.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance for any assistance.